# Does Outlook 2016 Calendar have varying "detail" levels like 2010 did?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I recently installed office 2016 and noticed that there is no obvious way to adjust the level of detail on calendar events for various calendar views.  For example,  in Outlook 2010 when you switched to "month view" you could select "High Detail, Medium Detail, and Low Detail" from a pull-down in the view tab.

Was this feature deleted for Outlook 2016? Because I cannot seem to locate it anywhere and help searches have not turned anything up.

Comment: Looks like this was removed in 2013, and remains gone in 2016.  What details are you trying to see/hide?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.  I'm helping to train new people during our switchover from 2010 to 2016 and I'm trying to answer all of their questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that this feature was removed in Outlook 2013, and remains deleted in Outlook 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the dates you want displayed using the date navigator, small calendar to the left.
It will then display the highlighted dates on your calendars with much more detail.

The calendar was defaulting to 6 weeks and wouldn't "preview" anything.  I highlighted 3 weeks in the navigator and got all the detail I needed.

Comment: This is for the latest outlook 365 2020